# Cannot find python xlrd version

Tags: python, excel, version, package, xlrd

I have been using `xlrd` within python. However, `xlrd`does not seem to provide a standard way to find its version number! I have tried:

- `xlrd.version()`
- `xlrd.__version__`
- `xlrd.version`
- `xlrd.VERSION`
- `xlrd.VERSION()`

Comment: The bold typing is a result of my not knowing the formatting rules here. It should include a double underscore before and after the name.

Comment: You need to enclose the text between `` for it to show up as code.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that next time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've almost got it: `xlrd.__VERSION__`.

Usually it's useful to see available attributes and methods by calling [dir](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir): `dir(xlrd)`.

---

You can even iterate through the results of `dir()` see if `version` is inside:

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> getattr(xlrd, next(item for item in dir(xlrd) if 'version' in item.lower()))
'0.9.3'
```

---

A more reliable way, that would work for any installed package, is to use [`pkg_resources`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html):

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("xlrd").version
'0.9.3'
```

Comment: This is extremely useful to know. Thanks for the answer and the tip on using the dir function in the future.